# how to select a doc from a firebase according to their time of creation?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning the firebase and currently working on the project as well. I m bad at setting queries through the Database.

here is my firebase db structure

[image]

What I want is to select the newest document (according to their time of creation Or 'created' variable in them ) from the subscriptions' collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using firebase's javascript library, you can do something like this:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection("subscriptions").orderBy("created", "desc").limit(1).get()
```

This will return the latest document. If you want to increase the number of documents returned by the query, simply update the `limit` parameter to be the desired number.

For more [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)